# Magento REST API Cannot add products (Nonce and Invalid attribute SKU)

Tags: rest, magento, magento-1.9

I'm new to Magento REST APIs. I've been trying to POST a product to my Magento store through Postman. OAuth 1.0 is authorized and I've checked it by updating a product and getting product details which works fine.
The problem arises when I try to insert a new product. First time when I click the send button it shows me the Error **oauth_problem=nonce_used**

[This the screen shot for the first error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpSRz.png)

And when I try to send it again it shows me a different error **Invalid attribute \"sku\": The value of attribute \"SKU\" must be unique**

[This is the screen shot for 2nd error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cO8LW.png)